# Testing rspec post with Rails JSONAPI::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, rspec-rails, json-api

I'm using the jsonapi-serializers gem and am having some trouble with figuring out how to test a post request with rspec and a json payload. I know it works because I can use postman and send json and it successfully creates the new object, but I'm not sure why I can't get the rspec test to work.

Here's the api controller method:

```
def create
  @sections = @survey.sections.all
  if @sections.save
    render json: serialize_model(@section), status: :created
  else
    render json: @section.errors, status: :unproccessable_entity
  end
end
```

The `serialize_model` is just a helper for `JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize`

Here's my current rspec tests for that controller:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  before :each do
    @section_params = { section: { title: 'Section 1', position: 'top', instructions: 'fill it out' } }
    post '/surveys/1/sections', @section_params.to_json, format: :json
  end

  it 'responds successfully with an HTTP 201 status code' do
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
  end
end
```

I've tried a few different things and can't figure out how to fix this. If I make a post the that url with Postman and that exact json payload, it successfully creates the new section.

The get request tests are working fine, I'm just not sure how to handle the json request data with rspec and the jsonapi-serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Substitute `YourApiController` for whatever you named yours

```
describe YourApiController, type: :controller do
  context "#create" do
    it 'responds successfully with an HTTP 201 status code' do
      params = { section: { title: 'Section 1', position: 'top', instructions: 'fill it out' } }
      survey = double(:survey, sections: [])
      sections = double(:sections)
      section = double(:section)
      expect(survey).to receive(:sections).and_return(sections)
      expect(sections).to receive(:all).and_return(sections)
      expect(sections).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
      expect(controller).to receive(:serialize_model).with(section)
      post :create, params, format: :json
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      expect(assigns(:sections)).to eq sections
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!